# JSON Processing - Sending JSON text string to JSP, how to process in JSP with JSONObject or GSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsp, gson

I am sendng json data to another jsp page - for testing really.

You enter a JSON formatted string in a text field on my jsp from. I submit this through a form request, handled by jquery processing. It is sent to a receiver JSP. I am using the following code to do this.

Before I send it I get the data using:

```
jsonData = $form.find( 'textarea[name="jsonData"]' ).val();
```

I then do:

```
var parsedJsonObject = $.parseJSON(jsonData);
```

This is my send code:

```
$.ajax({  
    type:       "POST",  
    url:        "receiver.jsp",  
    data:       "jsonData=" + parsedJsonObject, // This is an object, created using parseJSON
    success:    function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {  
                    alert('Success : ' + data);  
                    alert('textStatus : ' + textStatus);  
                    alert('jqXHR : ' + jqXHR);  
                    var jsonJqXHR = JSON.stringify(jqXHR); 
                    alert('jsonJqXHR : ' + jsonJqXHR);  
    },  
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){  
        alert('Error xhr : ' + xhr.status);  
        alert('Error thrown error: ' + thrownError);  
    }, 
    //complete: alert('complete'), 
    dataType:   "text" // xml, json, script, text, html                         
});
```

In my JSP, I do a:

```
String jsonData = request.getParameter("jsonData");
System.out.println("jsonData : " + jsonData);
```

This returns a output of: json : "[object Object]"

How do I deserialize it? I have done some things with gson, but when I have tried:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
System.out.println("json = " + json); // I still get an output of: json = "[object Object]"
gson.fromJson(json, MyClass.class);
```

I get an error:

```
servlet jsp threw exception: com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Expecting object found: "[object Object]"
```

Can anyone help please on the way I need to get this data out of the object?

Comment: What's the `obj` that makes `gson.toJson(obj);` give you `"[object Object]"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AJAX call, `data: "jsonData=" + parsedJsonObject` doesn't do what you intend:

It just gives you a string like `[object Object]`, not the JSON representation you're looking for.

Use `data: "jsonData=" + JSON.stringify(parsedJsonObject)` or some jQuery equivalent.

Comment: So am I right in thinking, that you can't send the parsedJsonObject (Object) via my Ajax Post?

Comment: The `parsedJsonObject` as an object only exists in the memory/Javascript engine of your browser, if you want to POST it somewhere, you need some kind of transport encoding. For a Javascript object this naturally is a JSON string which `JSON.stringify()` will easily provide you.

Comment: Hi @Philipp Reichart So if I use: var parsedJsonObject = $.parseJSON(jsonData); this will parse the data string I have - ensure that its' in valid format and I use the stringify to put it back into a text string to pass?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.kodejava.org/examples/585.html

You need a class to map it to that's the same fields.  What fields are you sending and what fields are in the class you are trying to map it to?

Paste the JSON into here and verify it's ok and not invalid and that your fields match up.

http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

http://www.jsonviewer.com/

or get a JSON plugin

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jsonview/